# How to calculate average using aggregated values in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

If this is a small portion of document looks like,

```
{ "metricName" : "call", "createdDate" : "2019-10-31T00:00:00.000Z", "responseCode: "200" }
{ "metricName" : "email", "createdDate" : "2019-10-31T00:00:00.000Z", "responseCode: "400" }
{ "metricName" : "chat", "createdDate" : "2019-10-31T00:00:00.000Z", "responseCode: "300" }
.
.
```

I need to do below operations in one query.

1. The query should allow me to filter records based on createdDate, responseCode and metricName.
2. The result needs to be grouped by metricName and createdDate.
3. Also, need to extract a count of records for each group by.
4. I need to find the average of records containing a specific responseCode based on records created at the same instance ( for a given createdDate).

Answer (score 0):

The aggregations API allows grouping by multiple fields, using sub-aggregations. Suppose you want to group by fields field1, field2 and field3:

Your 1,2 and 3 questions are solved with this query.

```
POST /stackoverflow/_search?size=0
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "createdDate": {
                            "query": "2019-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
                            "slop": 0,
                            "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "responseCode": {
                            "query": "200",
                            "slop": 0,
                            "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "metricName": {
                            "query": "call",
                            "slop": 0,
                            "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggr": {
        "agg1": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "metricName",
                "size": 10,
                "order": [
                    {
                        "_count": "desc"
                    },
                    {
                        "_key": "asc"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "agg2": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "createdDate",
                    "size": 10,
                    "order": [
                        {
                            "_count": "desc"
                        },
                        {
                            "_key": "asc"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```